# How to display autorefresh page in ASP.NET MVC when database change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, reload

I have to reload the page as soon as the data inside the database changes.

I saw that you can also do it with the meta tag directly in the html but this re-arises the page every few seconds and that's not what I want

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
```

Some suggestions?

Comment: That's a *very* broad question. Your server code needs to send a notification to all browsers that display the same data. That's no different than any other notification scenario, where eg the server sends a message to the browser. A high-level solution is to use SignalR and add *Javascript* code that reloads the data when a refresh notification is sent

Comment: i am trying to do it with signalr but i can't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528272/signalr-notification-reload-always-the-page