# SignalR notification reload always the pyhjyjage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, signalr

I was using signalR to manage database changes, when it happens I want to update the page to other users so that they see the change. But what I've done so far always loads, here is the code:

**INDEX**

```
@section scripts{  
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.3.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function () {  
            var hubNotify = $.connection.Connection4Hub;  
  
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {  
                getAll();
            });  
  
            hubNotify.client.GetUpdateData = function () {  
                getAll();
            };
        });  
                          
        function getAll() {  
            var model = $('#dataModel');  
            $.ajax({  
                url: '/Manage/GetUpdateData',  
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',  
                type: 'GET',  
                dataType: 'html',  
                success: function(result) { model.empty().append(result); }  
            });                           
            location.reload();
        }  
    </script>  
}
```

**Connect4Hub**

```
public class Connect4Hub : Hub
    {
        public static void BroadcastData()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Connect4Hub>();
            context.Clients.All.GetUpdateData();
        }
    }
```

**MANAGE**

```
public ActionResult GetUpdateData()
        {
            return PartialView("Index", db.Matches.ToList());
        }
```

**UPDATE**

In the console while running i get this error

> Uncaught Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. .
> start jQuery
>  https://localhost:44398/:216
> jQuery 2
> mightThrow
> process

Comment: Your own code explicitly reloads the entire pagd with `location.reload()`

Comment: yeah, i want it only on database change, how i can do that?

Comment: You're already doing that. When the *server* sends a notification to your browser, the browser will retrieve all results again. And then, call `reload` which results in reloading the entire document and yet another reload of the data. For starters, remove `reload`. If your JS framework uses data binding, it should refresh itself from the changed model

Comment: what i did now keeps loading the page indefinitely even if i don't change the database @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: So remove `reload`.

Comment: I try to do that

Comment: without reload the page is not loaded when the database changes @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Confirm that `result` is not empty with perhaps `console.log(result)` inside your success function. Also you might as well overwrite whole `#dataModel` since you're fetching everything, no need to append. `$('#dataModel').html(result)`.

Comment: @Wubbler i tried it and `result` isn't empty, if i remove `$('#dataModel').html(result)` nothing is shown